# Wordpress search result configuration

Tags: wordpress

I am building a website via wordpress. Currently I am facing a problem with the search results.How can I configure this page(the search result page).I am using an astra theme, if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**search.php** template responds for showing search results page

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct control on WP loop in Astra theme (bad analogy here loop means records available for the current query it may be one for e.g. single post/page have one record or more than one for archive pages)

But you can unhook and do the customization function and hooked it back to the tag responsible for rendering the search loop.

Here is the Astra official documentation for restricts [search results post](https://wpastra.com/docs/restrict-search-results-post/).